# Atom text editor write "highter than" symbol instead of colon, only in html?

Tags: html, atom-editor

How can I fix this bug? It only happens when I edit html so it's not the keyboard

Comment: What bug? Please provide more details especially by some code that is causing you issues.

Comment: When I write html code, every time I press shift+fullStop to make a colon, the editor write a "greater than" symbol but this only happens with html.

Comment: I stumbled upon this as well. Did you install the autoclose-html package? Check https://github.com/mattberkowitz/autoclose-html/issues/128 (the issue talks about ":" being replaced by "<" but in the discussion it is noted that the colon gets replaced by ">").

Comment: For me too. Only happens in .htm and .php files. Using a Finnish keyboard and I have the Autoclose-HTML package installed, although the symbol for me is the ">". Disabling the Autoclose-HTML package fixes it. The package didn't seem to work for me anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Tobias Krogh said in his reply, you most likely have the Autoclose-HTML package installed.

Go into it's settings and disable the keybindings for it.
That fixed the issue on my end, so hopefully it will for you as well.

Comment: You have to go in the packages list and then in the settings of Autoclose-HTML package to disable the keybinding option.

Comment: There is now another option, too: You can check Legacy/International Mode.

Answer (score 0):

its appear cuz of AutoClose-HTML Atom make double signs in tags like this < so you have to erase one of them "<" and it worked for me.